# How to determine the first maximum value in a variable in R?

Tags: r

Following is a data frame x:

```
> x <- data.frame(a = c(0.1,0.1,0.1,1,1.1,1.2,2.1,3.1,3.3,3.2,3.1,2.1,2.0,0.1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3.1,4))
```

The first maximum value of a is 3.3 before the values start decreasing. How can I determine this value using code without looking at the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
filter(x,lag(a)<a & a>lead(a))
```

Answer (score 4):

With base R I would go with

```
x[which(diff(x$a) < 0L)[1L],]
## [1] 3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

"which.max" is a little bit faster:

```
> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:1000000 ) { a <- x$a[which.max(diff(x$a)<0)] }
+ )
       User      System verstrichen 
      62.42        0.01       62.65 

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:1000000 ) { b <- x[which(diff(x$a) < 0L)[1L],] }
+ )
       User      System verstrichen 
     111.43        0.00      112.14 
>
```

The result is the same:

```
> a
[1] 3.3
> b
[1] 3.3
```